# Publishing Flutter app to Galaxy/Amazon/Microsoft Stores?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, windows-store, amazon-appstore, galaxy-apps

Im looking to refactor my app - however am also looking at switching to Flutter

Considering I want to publish my Play Store app onto Samsung Galaxy Store, Amazon Store and Microsoft Windows Store is Flutter compatible?

I ask because these stores have their own consoles, require their own IAPs and some other APIs ( like Amazon Geo ) so want to determine if this is a forcing function for my biz

Thanks

The app in question [www.sprocket.bike/app](https://www.sprocket.bike/app)

Comment: So basically For the Galaxy Store what you need is an apk or aab which is same as playstore, don't know about Amazon store but if it is for android then all is the same but for the Microsoft windows store it depends like you want to publish an exe or apk but as i know it supports both as of now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flutter is fine for Samsung Galaxy store as they only need an apk which Flutter will generate for you. Windows is also fine with Flutter. Amazon app store also only requires an APK similar to the Galaxy store, so once again you're fine. The important thing with all of these is it seems you just need a .apk version of your app, so really you just need an android compatible app.

The main draw of Flutter is that you can also publish to iOS & macOS. If it's just these stores you're interested in, personally I'd just use native Kotlin.